# Why does <<ListboxSelect>> binding in Python's Tkinter trigger spuriously when double clicking an Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tkinter-entry, event-binding

As part of a larger bock of code, I discovered an oddity with tkinter listbox bindings. The below code gives a breakdown of the issue. When binding a listbox with 'listboxselected', selecting an item within that listbox, then double left clicking on the Entry, the listboxselected event is triggered once.

I have tested this in python 3.3.2, 3.6.3 and 3.7.1. The error only occurs in the two latter versions. I have checked the doc's and cant find any updates to cause this issue. Does anyone have any idea to why this behaviour may be occurring?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Listbox, Entry, Button
from functools import partial

root = Tk()

myList = Listbox(root)
myList.insert("end", "spam", "eggs", "chips")
myList.pack()
myList.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", partial(print))

myEntry = Entry(root)
myEntry.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't duplicate this on OSX, but my guess is that when you double-click in the entry, the text in the entry is selected. When the text is selected (even if there is nothing to select), the item in the listbox is de-selected. The de-selection triggers the binding.

If you want to be able to have something in both the listbox and entry selected, set `exportselection=False` in the listbox.

Comment: That's spot on thanks! Had me scratching my head for a while.